# regarding string builder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stringbuilder

Friends

i'm using string builder for generating Passenger List in which i have used a tables i want to add background image into this Passenger List. what i did is i have taken one main table --

```
strHTML1.Append("<table align=center cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>");
strHTML1.Append("<tr>");
strHTML1.Append("<td  style='background-image:url('../Images/bg-m.gif')>");
strHTML1.Append("Passenger");
strHTML1.Append("</td>");
strHTML1.Append("</tr>");
.........
```

the prob is this it is not show the background image.

pls help me out to come out from this prob

thanks in advance

Comment: Remove single-quote - url(../Images/bg-m.gif)

Comment: Your image folder is on root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the quotations:

```
strHTML1.Append("<td  style=\"background-image:url('../Images/bg-m.gif')\">");
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks ! – Alex,, friend do you know how to display dropdownlist in stringbuilder??

Comment: @Kayalriyaz, sounds cool! As Sunny said, it is best to ask another question for that

Comment: @Alex--yea just now i raised a question 'regarding string builder(how to display dropdownlist in stringbuilder)'

Answer (score 0):

I just copy paste your cs code and test on my end it works fine when i make some changes on image path as my Image folder is on root

```
    StringBuilder strHTML1 = new StringBuilder();
    strHTML1.Append("<table align=center cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>");
    strHTML1.Append("<tr>");
    strHTML1.Append("<td  style=\"background-image:url('Images/cancel_button.png')\">");
    strHTML1.Append("Passenger");
    strHTML1.Append("</td>");
    strHTML1.Append("</tr>");

    Literal1.Text = strHTML1.ToString();
```

Hope it also works for you

Comment: This too worked for me, thanks ! – Sunny,, friend do you know how to display dropdownlist in stringbuilder??

Comment: Can you ask this one as a new  question so that i can give answer

Comment: yea just now i raised a question

Comment: can you give me link of that one ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097423/regarding-string-builderhow-to-display-dropdownlist-in-stringbuilder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12731/discussion-between-sunny-and-kayalriyaz)