# regarding string builder(how to display dropdownlist in stringbuilder)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stringbuilder

Friends

i'm using string builder for generating Passenger List in which i have used a tables i want to add dropdownlist into this Passenger . what i did is i have taken one main table --

```
strHTML1.Append("<table align=center cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>");
strHTML1.Append("<tr>");
strHTML1.Append("<td>");
strHTML1.Append("Passenger");
strHTML1.Append("</td>");
strHTML1.Append("</tr>");
strHTML1.Append("<tr>");
strHTML1.Append("<td>");
strHTML1.Append("<asp:dropdownlist id='drp' runat='server' width='140px'>");
strHTML1.Append("</asp:dropdownlist>");
strHTML1.Append("</td>");
strHTML1.Append("</tr>")
.........
```

the prob is it is not show the dropdownlist when i run the project.

pls help me out to come out from this prob

thanks in advance

Comment: Just a thought, why not use HtmlTextWriter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx ?

Comment: What method are you running the above code in? Is it in Page_Load?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as per my knowledge you can add HTML tag using literal.You can do this by :

```
    StringBuilder strHTML1 = new StringBuilder();
    strHTML1.Append("<select>");
    strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'volvo'>Volvo</Option>");
    strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'saab'>Saab</Option>");
    strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'mercedes'>Mercedes</Option>");
    strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'audi'>Audi</Option>");
    strHTML1.Append("</select>");
```

and final code is :

```
  strHTML1.Append("<table align=center cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>");
  strHTML1.Append("<tr>");
  strHTML1.Append("<td>");
  strHTML1.Append("Passenger");
  strHTML1.Append("</td>");
  strHTML1.Append("</tr>");
  strHTML1.Append("<tr>");
  strHTML1.Append("<td>");
  strHTML1.Append("<select>");
  strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'volvo'>Volvo</Option>");
  strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'saab'>Saab</Option>");
  strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'mercedes'>Mercedes</Option>");
  strHTML1.Append("<Option value = 'audi'>Audi</Option>");
  strHTML1.Append("</select>");
  strHTML1.Append("</td>");
  strHTML1.Append("</tr>");
  strHTML1.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: @Sunny--> frd is there any solution for display asp:dropdownlist,asp:textbox??